# How can I restore a winapi window if it's minimized?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have tried many functions, such as `ShowWindow` & `IsWindowVisible` to at least try to give the result if the window is minimized, let alone restore it. These functions constantly return false whether the window is minimized or not. 
I have also tried using `GetWindowPlacement`with `SetWindowPlacement` with no success.
My `HWND` finds Chrome with `FindWindow(TEXT("Chrome_WidgetWin_1"), NULL);` which is successful, but I want to test/restore the window if it's minimized and these past 10 hours has nothing to show for it.

Comment: Just to be sure you're using the Win32 API?

Comment: I am using a console at the moment, but using the Windows header. Can this not be done using console?

Comment: Try [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bde4870-1599-4958-9ab4-902fa98ba53a/how-do-i-maximizeminimize-applications-programmatically-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: At first trying `ShowWindowAsync(chrome, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);` it actually worked. It brought the window out of minimize. But running it a few more times, it stopped working?

Comment: [`OpenIcon()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Of course, you said `IsIconic()` is returning false...

Comment: Have you tried running your process with elevated privileges (i.e. run as admin)?  I would imagine modifying the window position of another process requires elevation.

Comment: @MooseBoys: You are assuming wrong. A process is allowed to control windows of other processes, unless those other processes are elevated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome has an invisible window with the same name. The invisible window simply needs to be skipped.

```
void show(HWND hwnd)
{
    //We can just call ShowWindow & SetForegroundWindow to bring hwnd to front. 
    //But that would also take maximized window out of maximized state. 
    //Using GetWindowPlacement preserves maximized state
    WINDOWPLACEMENT place;
    memset(&place, 0, sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
    place.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
    GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &place);

    switch (place.showCmd)
    {
    case SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
        break;
    case SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
        break;
    default:
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
        break;
    }

    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR cmdline, int nshow)
{
    const wchar_t *classname = L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1";

    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    for (;;)
    {
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(0, hwnd, classname, 0);
        if (!hwnd) break;

        //skip Chrome's invisible winodw
        if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        {
            wchar_t buf[260];
            GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, 260);
            OutputDebugString(buf);
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");

            show(hwnd);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In theory that should work. However I have tested this method without success. I even had no other applications running except chrome(minimized) and of course, the program I'm making. Would also like to note, for some reason `IsIconic` always returns false for me.

Comment: I see what you mean. Each chrome window has at least one child, if the top window won't cooperate then go after the child.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why chrome won't cooperate, and this brute force kind of method is exactly what I'm looking for. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks Kilo King. I made another edit which looks smoother. Actually, I am still not sure why Chrome is acting weird or how its windows are arranged, but at least it seems to work consistently.

Comment: It appears that you do not understand the difference between the *active window* and the *foreground window*. This is explained under [Window Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx). Bonus reading: [Eventually, nothing is special any more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/06/8969399.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Windows documentation is not helpful here. The problem was Chrome has invisible windows. That's solved. I used @Kilo King's suggestion of `WINDOWPLACEMENT`, so now Window is brought to front correctly. I had put in some nonsense earlier for `SetActiveWindow` etc. it was out of frustration, I removed that.

Comment: You were calling `SetActiveWindow` for a window in another process. The documentation is helpful in explaining, why this is not possible (the documentation for [SetActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311.aspx) even spells this out explicitly).

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani I appreciate the revision as this works correctly 100% now and not just consistently. Thank you very much, can't express that enough. Solved my issue & explained why I was having the issue with chrome.