# Send "button pressed" message to UnityWndClass

Tags: c++, winapi

I have 3D game and i need to press buttons in this game from another application. Spy++ says that window of the game is UnityWndClass. When i pressing buttons in game, window recives only mouse messages like `WM_SETCURSOR`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` etc, but when i try to send `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` with coordinates of the button from another window nothing happend. Why? Any ideas how to press buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WM_SETCURSOR` is for changing the cursor image of your own window. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` are notification messages sent after mouse click. `WM_LBUTTONXXX` messages are probably not handled by the main Window procedure.

To fake mouse input, you can use `mouse_event` or `SendInput`. For example, this moves cursor to `x=10 / y=10` and and clicks left mouse.

```
int x = 10 * 65536 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int y = 10 * 65536 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or use `SendInput` for multiple calls *(see comments)*

```
INPUT input[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    memset(&input[i], 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    input[i].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
}

input[0].mi.dx = x;
input[0].mi.dy = y;
input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
input[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
SendInput(3, input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Window should be at least visible and preferably be active. You can use `SetForegroundWindow`. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837548/4603670) to make sure window is visible and active.

**Other alternatives:**

Use Spy++ to get information about the button which you want to press.

For example, if this was Windows Calculator, you can spy on calculator's buttons, it shows calculator button <kbd>2</kbd> has ID set to 0x84. You can send `WM_COMMAND` with `WPARAM` set to 0x84 to simulate button press.

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, L"Calculator");
if (IsWindow(hwnd))
{
    //this should put "234" in to calculator's edit box
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 0x84, 0);    
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 0x85, 0);    
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 0x86, 0);    
}
```

Comment: Window should be active, when i do fake mouse input?

Comment: Yes, Window should be at least visible and it's better if it is active. I update the answer.

Comment: A window **must** have input focus to receive input (synthesized or authentic). Please do read the documentation for [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) again. Passing `1` for `nInputs` is a bug. The *Remarks* section explains, why. Plus, none of your proposed hacks resemble a robust solution. The correct way is to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), which doesn't mandate a particular window to have input focus at any point.

Comment: @IInspectable I can't see that in *Remarks* section for `SendInput` documentation. Please add another answer and show the correct usage. I have multiple `SendInput` calls which should be combined in one array.  I made it as individual calls for demonstration purposes. Is that a bug? Surely it's not a bug if there was a single call? If UI Automation can be demonstrated for any random program on any random function then example would be useful. OP doesn't know anything about the 3rd party program except its window class name.

Comment: Since the 3rd party application is using standard windows controls, it has built-in support for UI Automation already. [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx): *"The SendInput function inserts the events in the INPUT structures serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream. **These events are not interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events** inserted either by the user (with the keyboard or mouse) or by calls to keybd_event, mouse_event, or other calls to SendInput."*

Comment: I had to look up *interspersed* in dictionary, I think I should put that in an array for multiple calls? I updated the answer.

Comment: That is correct. If you don't send them in a single transaction, you're running the risk that the mouse pointer gets move in between your first and second mouse event, resulting in a click at some undesired location, for example. Another problem that this solves is running into impossible states (e.g. an application receiving two `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages without a corresponding `WM_LBUTTONUP` in between).

Comment: Unfortunately there are no `WM_COMMAND` messages, only mouse move and click messages. Anyway, i use `mouse_event` function and it's work perfect. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @mr.Force: Right at the top of [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx): *"This function has been superseded. Use [**SendInput**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead."* The reason why it has been superseded is, because it **doesn't** work perfect.

Comment: Thanks alot,  guys. `SendInput` really works better.