# IsIconic() behavior varies depending on the environment

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'd like to use IsIconic function to check whether the specified window is minimized (iconic).

IsIconic function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/ms633527(v=vs.85).aspx

My code works properly in certain environments, but it does not work in other environments.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class Form1

   <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
   Public Shared Function IsIconic(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Long
   End Function

   <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
   Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
   End Function


   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, "Google - Google Chrome")

       If CBool(IsIconic(hWnd)) Then
           Debug.WriteLine("Chrome is iconic.")
       Else
           Debug.WriteLine("Chrome is not iconic.")
       End If
   End Sub

End Class
```

When I run it with 64 bit Windows 7 OS, I can determine correctly whether Chrome is iconified.
However, when running on 32 bit Windows 7 OS, "Chrome is iconic." is always displayed in the immediate window regardless of whether or not Chrome is actually iconified.

Could you tell me why this difference occurs?
Is this phenomenon caused by the difference in OS bit number? Or something else?

Comment: I don't know whether changing it will solve your issue, but your return type of the `IsIconic()` function is wrong. `As Long` should be `As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean`.

Comment: I also found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837548/3740093) stating that Google Chrome uses some sort of invisible window. Whether it has the same title that you specify I find unlikely, but perhaps you can try checking `IsWindowVisible()` as well just to be sure?

Comment: Use `Spy++` from the Visual Studio toolset to see what windows Chrome had created on your machine. My guess is that your issue is that Chrome is doing something "undocumented" that throws off that API.

Comment: Thanks to Visual Vincent the problem was solved ! The program now works correctly after changing the return type from `Long` to `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean`.
I'd like you to recomment the message as Answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment. Glad it worked, although I didn't think it would! ;) -- Tip for the future: To notify someone about comments you can type an '@' followed by their name _**without spaces**_, for example: `@VisualVincent YOUR MESSAGE HERE` (it doesn't matter _where_ in the comment you type this though). The owner of a post always gets notified of new comments.

Comment: I wrote an answer for you below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return type of the [**`IsIconic()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527(v=vs.85).aspx) is wrong.

This:

```
Public Shared Function IsIconic(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Long
```

...should be this:

```
Public Shared Function IsIconic(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
```

This also means that you can (and should) change:

```
If CBool(IsIconic(hWnd)) Then
    Debug.WriteLine("Chrome is iconic.")
Else
    ...
```

to:

```
If IsIconic(hWnd) Then
    Debug.WriteLine("Chrome is iconic.")
Else
    ...
```